# Rails - LoadError (Expected xxx/controllers/application_controller.rb to define ApplicationController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2

I build a backend service (nginx + passenger + rails) on AWS.
My service is running as expected most of the time but sometimes goes wrong when passenger creates a weird new process to handle request:

```
[INFO] Started POST "/apixxxxxx"
[FATAL] LoadError (Expected /xxxxxxxx/app/controllers/application_controller.rb to define ApplicationController):
[INFO] Started POST "/apixxxxxx"
[FATAL] ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController):
[INFO] Started POST "/apioooooo"
[FATAL] ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController):
...
```

It has some signature on this weird process:

- Other ruby process still works fine when this specific weird ruby process keeps failing on every new request.
- If error happens, it always starts by the "LoadError" in the beginning of the process's first request.
- This kind of "uninitialized constant" error keeps forever as long as this process is alive.

***new added information**:

- According to rails log, the same api can reply without error in other 'normal' passenger process. I exclude the problem about typo or rails naming convention.

Here is some information of my machine:

- ec2 type : m4.large
- storage : general purpose SSD (use EBS)
- system : ubuntu 14.04.2 (not AWS version)
- application : version 1.8.1, passenger 5.0.26, Rails 3.2.22.2, ruby 2.2.4p230, sidekiq 4.1.1

I also googled some keyword like "AWS EBS volume's IOPS limit" or "sidekiq thread" with this LoadError issue but no luck. Is there any new direction to investigate this problem?

Comment: Is your ApplicationController the default? Have you added something to it? Sometimes a typo when you are adding something...

Comment: You got this error because you violated Rails naming convention. `ApplicationController` **MUST** be defined in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, not elsewhere.

Comment: [For Ed de Almeida]  Yes, I did some modification on ApplicationController and it worked as expected under other 'normal' passenger process. Therefore it should not be a typo issue.

Comment: [For Aetherus] Thanks for your remind about the naming convention, I didn't follow the naming rule to all my controllers in the project. Is it reasonable that one process failed to load file and the other one succeed because of naming rule violation?